# Can I get the gradient of a tensor with respect to the input without applying the input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor, tensorflow-gradient

For example, I need to compute the gradient of the `cross_entropy` with respect to `x`, but I need to apply another value to the gradient function.

That is:

```
f'(x)|x = x_t
```

I think `tf.gradients()` function will only give the gradient at `x = x`.
So does tensorflow provide any of this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The result of [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) is a *tensor* (list of tensors in general), not a *float* value. In a way, this tensor *is* a function: it can be evaluated in *any* point. The client only needs to feed the desired input value.

Example:

```
features = 3
n_samples = 10
hidden = 1

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[n_samples, features])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[n_samples])

W = tf.Variable(np.ones([features, hidden]), dtype=tf.float32, name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(np.ones([hidden]), dtype=tf.float32, name="bias")

pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(pred - Y, 2))

dc_dw, dc_db = tf.gradients(cost, [W, b])

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Let's compute `dc_dw` at `ones` matrix.
print(dc_dw.eval(feed_dict={X: np.ones([n_samples, features]), 
                            Y: np.ones([n_samples])}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But in fact I need to update a new variable x_t, the initial value of which is x, according to the derivative. Actually my original thought is to keep the original graph but just add a new node x_t, and now it seems impossible. I think I need to do a lot of modification to my model to achieve this goal.